# Type safety for complex arithmetic in C99

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, implicit-conversion, complex-numbers

I'm using C's complex arithmetic support and ran into some surprising and undesirable behavior. Complex values seem to be implicitly convertible to real ones, discarding the imaginary part.

Consider the following:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float complex getComplex(float real, float imag)
{
    return real + imag * I;
}

int main()
{
    const float /* missing complex! */ c = getComplex(25, 6) / getComplex(2, 4);
    printf("%f + %f J\n", crealf(c), cimag(c));
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to receive some warning that I am assigning a `float complex` to a `float` or perhaps calling `crealf` and `cimagf` on a non-complex value, but this builds cleanly on GCC 5.1, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` switches. Clang 3.6.1 at least emits such a warning:

```
wut.c:11:62: warning: implicit conversion discards imaginary component: '_Complex float' to 'float'
      [-Wconversion]
    const float /* missing complex! */ c = getComplex(25, 6) / getComplex(2, 4);
                                       ~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why can complex values "collapse" to real ones? Is there some verbiage about this in the standard? And is there some additional switch for GCC that can provide warnings about this behavior? It has already bitten us, and switching toolchains (to clang) for this project isn't feasible at present time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C11 final draft (N1570), 6.3.1.7 paragraph 2:

> When a value of complex type is converted to a real type, the imaginary part of the complex value is discarded and the value of the real part is converted according to the conversion rules for the corresponding real type.

Real types are integer and real floating types.

The C99 rationale explains the motivation behind this:

> In mathematics, when a complex is converted to real, the imaginary part is discarded.  C99 follows the same convention.

And (numbering is identical to C11):

> The specification in §6.3.1.6 and §6.3.1.7 match Fortran's.

Comment: Good to know. Any idea of how to get GCC to warn you that you're dropping the imaginary component?

Comment: @MattKline: Sadly no, but you could try requesting it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: It's actually already in GCC 6 as per https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48956 . Backporting doesn't look horrible from looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/c-family/c-common.c?r1=223193&r2=223223&pathrev=223223 and https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/c-family/c-common.h?r1=223098&r2=223223&pathrev=223223

Comment: "In mathematics, when a complex is converted to real, the imaginary part is discarded. C99 follows the same convention."

This is not true. When such conversion in mathematics is needed, one almost always takes the modulus (sqrt(re^2 + im^2)) instead of real part.

Comment: @xyzzyz, well, really, when such conversion is needed, it is done *explicitly*, such as `|z|` (the modulus of `z`); implicit conversions are simply incorrect unless you can prove the 'complex' number is *already* a real.

Comment: @DavidX: that's true. My point is, taking real part of a complex number and discarding imaginary part is pretty unusual, much more often one takes modulus and discards argument.